# What is a good program structure for a simple hitTest multi level game in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I already made a 25 level simple hitTest game (mechanics are similar to flappy bird, when you hold down your mouse button the hero goes up, and if you aren't holding it he goes down and the goal is to come to the right side of the screen) and I have used a very bad code in my opinion. I have made one layer and one frame for all 25 levels, and in the frame I have a *onEnterFrame* function and in it 25 of these

```
if(currentFrame==x){
do something
}
```

because in some levels I have objects with certain instance names which I don't have on other levels, and if I don't have them on other levels, and they are mentioned in the code outside of the *if* function I get a syntax error (null object not found, I think it's error #1009) and also my game lags very much on AIR for android. In AS2 I have made this game much better but AS3 is pretty much different and I can't use the same 'strategy' for making the game. I would just appreciate if anyone could help me and tell me what should my code look like, like should I somehow avoid the syntax error of missing objects of certain instance names, or should I somehow write the code in each frame... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Luka, a simple way that you can avoid that problem is to simply check whether the object exists before you execute your code.

```
if(mc && /*other conditions*/){
//execute code
}
```

I feel your pain when it comes to putting a game together in a sloppy way. A couple years ago I put together an AS2 game that was spread out across about 25 flash files! I was too inexperienced and ignorant at the time to realize that that planning was not the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

AS3 is an object oriented programming language while AS2 is basically just a script language, they are not too similar... You better not use the same strategy as you did in AS2 because they are so different, that it will fail. Try to use classes, arrays / vectors. For example, create a Wall class and put the instances inside an array or a vector, then loop through the array/vector and search for collisions, if you remove a wall then remove it from that array/list aswell.